# jQuery UI sortable with CSS3 animations

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-animations, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with sortable widgets and the sorting works just fine, so I thought I'd spruce it up with some CSS3 animations. The animations work, but just one way!

When an item is dragged the animation to slightly tilt the item is animated as per the CSS. However, when an item is dropped I can't get the animation to reverse, so there is no animation when it is dropped and the item just snaps into place.

How can I also get an animation when an item is dropped?

Running code can be tried in the JSFiddle link below the code.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Container > .Item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.Container > .Item[class~=ui-sortable-helper] {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

---

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GTHvidsten/jjucxzdk/

Answer (score 0):

Updated, Adjusted selector for `transitionend` event to `ui-sortable-helper` - same `class` within `css` which has `transform` property - instead of `.Container`

Try utilizing [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Container").sortable({
        cursor : 'move',
        revert : true
    })
    .find(".Item[class~=ui-sortable-helper]")
    .on("transitionend", function(e) {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jjucxzdk/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work. I couldn't get it to work on my site either. (Actually, on my site the sortable-helper became invisible when I started dragging it after having added the `on("transitionend")` event.)

Comment: @GTHvidsten See updated post. Adjust selector for `transitionend` event; previously had event attached to `.Container` , instead of current element being having `transform` applied `.Item[class~=ui-sortable-helper]` . Note , interestingly , chrome / chromium appear to apply same effect whether event attached to parent container or actual element being transformed; tried previous jsfiddle at chrome / chromium ?

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. Your fork of my jsfiddle still doesn't transition the rotation back to zero, but snaps it back instead. This was tested on Chrome.